# Open Ethereum Syncing

Tags: synchronization, openethereum

How do I know if openethereum syncing is done and what should I do next?

This is what my current state looks like
[image: this is what my current state looks like]

Answer (score 0):

You may connect with web3 to your node and query the highest and current block. If both are same number then syncing is ready.

1. Create file **get_block_number.js**

```
const provider = 'http://localhost:8546'; // enter your specific RPC host and port
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider);
const web3 = new Web3(web3Provider);

web3.eth.isSyncing((error, sync) => {
    if (!error && sync) {
        console.log('sync =' , sync);
    } else {
        console.error('unable to get data')
    }

});
```

2. Run with

```
$ node ./get_block_number.js
```

3. Expected output during syncing

```
sync = {
  currentBlock: 89003,
  highestBlock: 128318,
  startingBlock: 0,
  warpChunksAmount: null,
  warpChunksProcessed: null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See where it says `Syncing #[some number]`?

The number in question is the block number which your node is up-to-date with. Once that number reaches the latest block on the chain, your node should be synced. You can check the latest block on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/).